# Is it idiomatic to say "you can throw the ball by swinging your hand from bottom up / from top down" in everyday English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

There are 2 ways to throw a ball.

*-You can throw the ball by swinging your hand from bottom up as the man in red in the picture.*

or

*-You can throw the ball by swinging your hand from top down as the woman in blue in the picture.*

But I am not sure the phrase "**to throw the ball  by swinging your hand from bottom up / from top down**" expresses accurately the 2 movements in everyday English as shown in the picture?

Comment: You see the descriptions in your diagram - overhand and underhand. Definitions of those words appear in many dictionaries. You may wish to check some of them.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, in Everyday conversation, do people use "overhand, underhand"?

Comment: Yes, those are the accepted terms. The only reason to form another description is to explain them.

Comment: In Britsh English "Overarm" and "Underarm".   But I don't really understand the question since the required words.  You can also "bowl", "pitch" "fling".  Gosh these days you can probably even "yeat".